# How to capitalize a function parameter in R?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot, capitalization

I am trying to make a function that returns a graph with a parameter that takes 3 different types of data, "short," "intermediate," and "long." However, I need to incorporate the names of these into the title of the graph, but I am not sure how to capitalize them.

I have the following code:

```
plotIsoform <- function(isoformtype){

dataIsoformPlotByStage <- dataIsoformPlot %>%
  filter(type == isoformtype) %>%
  select(condition, mean_condition) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = condition, values_from = mean_condition, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(cols = everything())

p1 <- ggplot(aes(x = stage1, y = stage2), data = dataIsoformPlotByStage) + 
  labs(title=paste("Length by Stage for", isoformtype, "Types"), 
       x ="Stage 1 Length", 
       y = "Stage 2 Length") +
  geom_point(size = 0.1) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson") + geom_abline()

return(p1)
}
```

When I run one example:

```
plotIsoform("short")
```

This returns a graph with "Length by Stage for short Types" for the title.

Is there a way to capitalize the "short" within the `paste()` function so it becomes "Length by Stage for Short Types" for the title?

Comment: If it's installed already: `gtools::capwords()`. Also look at the examples of `?chartr`

Comment: Its a bit dirty, but `capFirst <- function(x) paste0(toupper(substr(x,1,1)),substr(x,2,nchar(x)))` and `capFirst(isoformtype)` does the job of capitalizing the first letter.

Comment: And another option would be `stringr::str_to_title`